# Is there a way to intercept and modify the content of a print job and adding things like header and footer in it before actually printing it via c#?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, desktop

I need to seamlessly apply a default header/footer without user intervention whenever something is to be printed on a pc with a printer.

Where do I begin? Tried searching on github also and some paid apps.
Closest is from "printLimit - watermark"

Comment: I'm not familiiar with the windows printing system. But universally, you do not "intercept" print jobs, as these are kind of nontrivial. You might be able to add a "filter" to the printing chain, and if it's just by adding a special, modifying virtual printer driver

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you give me some keywords to search for? I'm not familiar with this kind of desktop development (webdev here) thanks in advance.

Comment: All the words I have I already put in my first comment. Honestly, I don't think operating systems like windows are meant to *allow* you to do that, unless they already come with such functionality. I don't think Windows does.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "printLimit - watermark" app was able to do it... Sadly only 30-day trial. Link: https://www.printlimit.com/mobile/print-watermark-software/

Comment: @MarcusMüller i tried searching for all the words you have already put in your first comment but sadly, nothing coherent resulted from it...